# Audio Quality degrades on HTML5 & Phaser

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, phaser-framework

We're using `AudioSprite`s for our character's dialog in a Phaser Game.  We're loading both `.mp3` and `.ogg` files to support the various browsers.  After loading the files on our state's `preload()` we decode them before playing.

We've got an issue on Safari where after about 20 minutes of gameplay, the audio begins to slow down and cut-off.  The cut-off makes sense as the audio sprite is only set to play for a certain amount of time, but I've no idea why the audio would slow down.

The issue on Chrome is similar, except the audio becomes filled with static.

The audio sprites are not very big, the VO is 18MB, the SFX is 209kB, and the background music is 2.1MB.

Here's the code that calls up the audio to play

```
/**
* Play an audio file
* @param soundKey {string} the preloaded sound or audio sprite key
* @param [marker] {string} the audio sprite marker key
* @param volume   {int}    the volume value; from 0-1
* @returns {Sound} a reference to the currently playing audio
*/
playAudio(soundKey, marker, volume = 1) {

  if (!this.game.playerData.general.dialogue) { return null }
  if (!this.game.cache.checkSoundKey(soundKey)) { console.warn('cannot find audio: '+soundKey); return null}

  if (marker) {
    let audio = this.game.sound.addSprite(soundKey)
    if (audio.get(marker)) {
      return audio.play(marker, volume)
    }
    else {
      console.warn('No Marker: ', marker, ' for audio ', audio)
      return null
    }
  } else {
    let audio = this.game.sound.add(soundKey)
    return (audio ? audio.play(volume) : null)
  }
}
```

everything else is hidden by the `Phaser` implementation.